# How to add dynamically the main parent pages's custom fields and their values to all sub-pages?

Tags: custom-field

I have a main parent page with multiple sub-pages. The main parent page has some custom fields (meta boxes?) with specific values. My intent is to add dynamically these custom fields and their values to all sub-pages. I searched a solution but without success. Is this possible? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent post ID is stored in `$post->post_parent`. So you can access the parent data by using that ID in `get_post_meta()`.

To get the ancestors use `get_post_ancestors( $post->ID )`. It returns an array of parent IDs, the last one is the highest. Let’s invent a helper function for the next examples:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_top_ancestor' ) )
{
    function get_top_ancestor( $post_id )
    {
        $ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $post_id );
        return empty ( $ancestors ) ? $post_id : end( $ancestors );
    }
}
```

Now we can use that helper in a filter for `the_content`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_78325_parent_meta' );

function wpse_78325_parent_meta( $content )
{
    global $post;
    if ( ! is_page() or empty ( $post->post_parent ) )
        return $content;

    $top_id = get_top_ancestor( $post->ID );

    if ( ! $data = get_post_meta( $top_id, 'demo_data', TRUE ) )
        return $content;

    $extra = sprintf(
        '<p>Meta data <code>demo_data</code> from <a href="%1$s">parent post</a>:</p>
        <pre>%2$s</pre>',
        get_permalink( $top_id ),
        esc_html( $data )
    );

    return $extra . $content;
}
```

Let’s say you have a parent page *Privacy Policy* with a custom field `demo_data` …

[image]

… and a child page *Security* …

[image]

… then the code above would produce this result:

[image]

---

In reply to your comment: You can use the parent post meta wherever you need it. In your case, I would filter `wp_nav_menu_args` and call `wp_nav_menu` with a static string for `menu`.

Sample code, not tested, just a draft. :)

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'wpse_78325_parent_menu_name' );

function wpse_78325_parent_menu_name( $args )
{
    if ( 'primary' !== $args['theme_location'] or ! is_page() )
        return $args;

    global $post;

    $top_id = get_top_ancestor( $post->ID );

    /* prepend this line with a # to switch the logic
    if ( ! $name = get_post_meta( $top_id, 'MenuName', TRUE ) )
        return $args;

    $args['menu'] = $name;
    /*/
    foreach ( $args as $key => $value ) // you can use custom keys here
    {
        if ( $new = get_post_meta( $top_id, 'MenuName', TRUE ) )
        {
            $args[ $key ] = $new;
            unset ( $new );
        }
    }
    /**/    

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: toscho, your function worked as you described. Now a small clarification. I have the next code in 'header.php' file: `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'fallback_cb' => 0, 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'menu' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'MenuName', true ) ) ); ?>`. 'MenuName' is the name of parent page Custom Field. What I want is that the child pages to copy dynamically this Custom Field with its value from the parent page as an own Custom Field and value. Is this possible?

Sorry I was not very clear.

Comment: **@toscho** You're a magician! Your code again worked! Thank you! And please excuse my boldness, but I have two more questions. 1) How to adapt the last code for multiple Custom Fields, when we know their names? and 2) How to implement more optimally this last code for the multi-level parent pages?

Comment: **@toscho** I think it's too late and I'm tired :). Forget the second question, the code works also for the multi-level parent pages. Now I am only interested in the first question.

Comment: @Iurie I have added a helper function to get the top parent and an example to use multiple custom fields, showing how to overwrite the menu arguments. You can use a custom array of keys instead of `$args` to provide the keys to search for.

Comment: **@toscho** I think that the first question is also solved. I will use your first code, because it is not related to navigation menu and it fits for my other purposes. Thank you again!