# Conditional statement for parent, child and grandchild pages

Tags: php, html, conditional-tags, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a conditional statement to check if the parent, child or grandchild is being displayed. This is what I've got so far:

```
<?php 

if ( is_page( 'about' ) || '29' == $post->post_parent ) {
    //Start of the custom code...
    while(has_sub_field('site_slideshows','option')):
    ?> <!-- Closing the PHP tag -->

        <div class="slideshow-slide" style="background-image:url(<?php the_sub_field('site_slideshows_slide_image'); ?>)">
            <div class="block-text" style="color: <?php the_sub_field('site_slideshows_slide_text_colour'); ?>;"><?php the_sub_field('site_slideshows_slide_text'); ?></div>
        </div>

    <?php //Opening the PHP tag again
    endwhile;

} elseif ( is_page( 'contact' ) || '31' == $post->post_parent ) {
    //Start of the custom code...
    while(has_sub_field('two_site_slideshows','option')):
    ?> <!-- Closing the PHP tag -->

        <div class="slideshow-slide" style="background-image:url(<?php the_sub_field('two_site_slideshows_slide_image'); ?>)">
            <div class="block-text" style="color: <?php the_sub_field('two_site_slide_text_colour'); ?>;"><?php the_sub_field('two_site_slideshows_slide_text'); ?></div>
        </div>

    <?php //Opening the PHP tag again
    endwhile;

}
?>
```

This will successfully check for the parent and child page, e.g. the `about` page and all the children of the `about` page, but how would I adjust these statements to include grandchild pages also? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `get_post_ancestors( $post )`. It returns an array of post IDs. The parent ID is the first entry, the grand parent the second and so on.

```
$ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $post );

if ( is_page( 'about' ) || in_array( '29', $ancestors ) )
{
    echo "This is About or one of its descendants";
}
elseif ( is_page( 'contact' ) || in_array( '31', $ancestors ) )
{
    echo "This is Contact or one of its descendants";
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, I'm not sure that's what I'm after though. As seen above `if ( is_page( 'about' ) || '29' == $post->post_parent ) {` allows me to display the same content on the parent page `about` and all it's children, I just want to add grandchildren into this if statement somehow, thus displaying the same content on the `about` page and all it's children and grandchildren. The same with the `elseif` statement for the `contact` page etc etc.

Comment: @user1374796 See my update to illustrate how to use the ancestors in your situation.

Comment: @user1374796 [This answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78328/73) might help too. You could store the data to display in a custom field an drop the hard coded post IDs.