# Exclude javascript in certain page url and all following url's after forward slash

Tags: functions, permalinks, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to exclude javascript from a couple of pages. But I want to target all the pages after the forward slash.

So I want to to target: `www.website.com/page-name/..`

So the page-name itself, alswell as all the siblings ever to come after it. So this url
`www.website.com/pagename/word/` but also `www.website.com/page-name/00/word/name/`

To in- and exclude my javascript I use the following in my `functions.php`:

```
function enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/js/jquery.js', false, null, true);
    wp_register_script( 'script_bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/js/bootstrap.min.js', false, null, true);
    wp_register_script( 'script_mmenu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js', false, null, true);
    // ... etc

    global $blog_id;  

    if( $blog_id == 3 && is_page( 17 ) || is_page( 20 ) || is_page( 22 ) || is_page( 24 ) )
    {
        // no js
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('script_bootstrap');
        wp_enqueue_script('script_mmenu');
        // ... etc
    }  
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: Are you strictly talking about pages (in the sense of a WordPress page) and its children?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional statement for parent, child and grandchild pages](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104367/conditional-statement-for-parent-child-and-grandchild-pages)

Comment: No, not strictly pages and it's children.

Comment: Can you then detail a bit more about what kind of content this is? I think it will be easier to go the WordPress route relating to actual content then brute-forcing via the URL.

Comment: @kraftner Not a duplicate of that post you suggested :). I don't know exactly how, but I think the stuff behind the website url is created dynamically in the included iframe.

Comment: Do you have a live site URL? To stick with your example what content is found under `www.website.com/pagename/word/`? I also don't get what an iframe has to do with it.

Comment: Yes, added the url in a Edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15029/discussion-between-remi-and-kraftner).

Comment: I see, this seems to come from some filter/facet search plugin you use and is therefore probably off topic here.